# How to choose a nib as a start up interface for Mac OS X application

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, storyboard

I'm new to macOS programming and recently I started working on [this project](https://github.com/maniramezan/PersianCalendar). Because I needed to share my `ViewController` and view with my Safari extension target, I ended up setting the view controller manually in `AppDelegate`:

```
let application = NSApplication.shared()

let initVC = ViewController.viewControllerWithNib()
let window = application.windows.first!
window.windowController?.contentViewController = initVC
window.contentViewController = initVC
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

I just left `Main.storyboard` to include the application portion since I couldn't figure out how to remove the storyboard and just use a xib as a startup for my application. Curently, I'm getting the following warning:

> Window Controller requires a content view controller, main.storyboard

I'm trying to figure out why the app is giving that warning and what's the way to get rid of it.

Comment: "since I couldn't figure out how to remove the storyboard and just use a xib as a startup for my application" Well then, maybe that's what you should ask about. See for example this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43399442/341994

Comment: @matt Thought that's implicit in the question, I can modify the title and the body to ask that question and then explain my workaround for it and the issue with the workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Diven mentioned, there's also an entry in plist file, `UIMainStoryboardFile` which tells which storyboard needs to be used. The equivalent of it for nibs is `NSMainNibFile`. But in addition to that, there were several other steps that I needed to do for replacing the storyboard fully with a nib which are mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7922150/1450348). Generally, what you need is following steps:

1. Add a new nib to your project and choose a name, e.i. `MainNib`. You can choose an `Application` nib template
2. Go to project, under target -> General -> Deployment Info -> choose the nib you created as `Main interface`
3. Go to your nib, as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7922150/1450348), add a blue object and assign its class to `AppDelegate` and then ctrl+drag/drop from `File owner` to that object and choose that one to be the `delegate`.

I updated the project with these changes.

Answer (score 1):

You should see the info.plist, I remember there is a need to delete the name NSMainxxxx.

Answer (score 0):

There's no more `Info.plist` you can easily select the target and check the `Info` tab. And there's `Main nib file base name` there.
[image]